# Using the same name for Azure Boards and Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, integration, azure-boards

How can I use the same organization name for my azure kanban boards and my azure pipeline?
when I want to register for azure pipeline, it tells me the organization name is already taken.

Comment: Knowing Azure DevOps, this is a strange question. Every Azure DevOps org can host both pipelines and Boards. It's not a matter of creating a Boards org and a Pipeline org. You create an org and it has both. What may be the case though, is that boards or pipelines has been turned off in the Organization you're in.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/set-services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if we want to launch Kanban boards or pipelines for the first time, we should follow the steps defined in official documentations and for each of them we have to create an organization name, since I have already created my Kanban boards, I couldn't define the same organization name for the pipeline too.
I was expecting that it can recognize this is the same organization as I logged in with the same username, but it couldn't.

The solution I found is that if we have already created Azure boards for an organization and we want to have pipelines for it too, we can add it by going to the Microsoft Marketplace and installing the required extensions such as Azure Pipelines.